# Making MS Access database searchable on the web

Tags: database, database-design, webforms

I would like to upload a pre-existing MS Access 2007 database to a website, and make it searchable with a web form. I know Caspio can do this easily (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIPanR6frik), but I would prefer an open source solution to save some $. Does anyone know of something comparable to Caspio which is free to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is helpful but I ran into it the other day:

http://www.zoho.com/creator/create-online-database.html